# cannot clone the source code because vsts permission

Tags: git, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting a job to deploy a java application into container using vsts

The job will :

- connect ssh to docker vm (using a sudo user, not root)
- clone the code from respestory  (using administrator account)
- put the code into folder into docker vm,
- generate a war file
- put the war file under tomcat server container

my vsts job show error after ssh connection to docker vm step :

```
TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier [Git Repository] does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
```

Into the docker VM, i can't also clone the project from vsts (show the same error) , though i have generate a public key and i put them into the vsts server

Anyone have ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

when i use `sudo git clone @link to git repo` from the docker vm

a error message like this :

```
Your Git command did not succeed.
Details:
    Public key authentication failed.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right way about generating a public key and put it into the vsts server(Azure DevOps)
Seems like Azure DevOps(VSTS) don't have your public SSH key to work with repo.
You can [create SSH key pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-1-create-your-ssh-keys) on your VM where a repository is needed to be cloned.
Please open Git Bash console tool(or just type in terminal) and create SSH key next command and with your Azure DevOps account email:

```
ssh-keygen -C "jamal@fabrikam.com"
```

After entering a changed command, press **ENTER** to save the key in the proposed file, then enter **y** key to overwrite if there already exists SSH key files.
Then console will ask to set a passphrase, just push ENTER button twice to make it empty.

Next step is to read public SSH key and copy it to Azure DevOps Security page. This command will output the public key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then select and copy to clipboard your public key (without any whitespaces). 
The last step is to [add the public key to Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-2--add-the-public-key-to-azure-devops-servicestfs). This link will show you where to add it.
After these steps, you can try again to clone the repository with source code.

Comment: not work with me, when i add the docker public key to SSH public keys in vsts, he show : 

Ajax request failed with status: The key you are attempting to add is already in use.

Seems the public key of docker vm is configured by local vsts account ; i can access to vsts only via LDAP credentials